# Calcular sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar , tengo que obtener un valor segun el mes que estoy procesando pero la condición es la siguiente 
lo tengo que realizar con sql server solo tengo una variable de entrada que es año/mes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla? ¿Qué código estás implementando? ¿Cuál es el error?  Por favor, [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/231840/edit) para completarla. Evita el uso de imágenes, poniendo mejor el texto del código y/o error que estás teniendo.

Comment: Piero, mi hermano, ya llevas bastante en el sitio para saber que este tipo de preguntas pueden ser cerradas por ser demasiado amplias, no tener intentos por resolver el problema, no poner qué errores obtienes, en fin, varias cosas. Pon más detalles o de lo contrario me temo que será cerrada porque no está claro lo que se pregunta

Comment: @Phi estas en todo lo cierto proceder a cerrarla

Comment: @Phi lo hice en una manera porque estaba desesperado pero me di una vuelta y lo solucione,

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo modificar tú pregunta y en el ejemplo creo que hay errores de definición.

Si bien entiendo, lo que necesitas es lo siguiente:

1. Si la variable cae en el 1° trimestre = [Valor]
2. Si la variable cae en el 2° trimestre = [Valor] * [Tasa]
3. Si la variable cae en el 3° trimestre = [Valor] * [Tasa] * [Tasa]
4. Si la variable cae en el 4° trimestre = No existe definición.

De ser así, te dejo el siguiente ejemplo que puede solucionar tu problema.

```
DECLARE @AnoMes nvarchar(7) = '2018/08',
        @AnoMesINT int

SET @AnoMesINT = CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(@AnoMes,6,7))

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @AnoMesINT BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN [Valor]
         WHEN @AnoMesINT BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN [Valor] * [Tasa]
         WHEN @AnoMesINT BETWEEN 7 AND 8 THEN [Valor] * [Tasa] * [Tasa 2] --En tu tabla no veo Tasa 2, Hay que exponenciar la columna [Tasa]?
    ELSE '?'
FROM [Tabla]
```

Comment: Y si mejor te esperas a que el OP coloque sus intentos?

Comment: Además si leyeras los comentarios ya hubieras notado que ya fue resuelta y que se le indicó que por no tener una muestra de su avance puede terminar cerrada

Comment: una vez que lo respondí al parecer también indico su solución, por lo demás preferí contribuir con una respuesta o alguna solución, ya que si bien no complemento en la totalidad su problema existen indicios de lo que necesitaba en la imagen adjunta.

Comment: De lo que necesita pero no de lo qué hace